# how can I write this if function?

Tags: laravel, if-statement

How can I write if function like this in laravel :

if **all of** $company->leaders->number == "1"
then return 1

else if **one of** $company->leaders->number == "0"
then return 0

This is the company :

[image]

And this is two leaders for company :

[image]

Comment: Define "all of" ; how many `$company->leaders` are there?

Comment: more than 1 $company->leader

Comment: is the `$company` object something you've created yourself or soemthing that you're using made by a 3rd party? ie. does it actually exist, yet?

Comment: leader is a " hasMany relationship"

Comment: yes it exist and leader is the relationship

Comment: will it always be either 0 and 1 or can it be a different number?

Comment: Please add your current relationships to your question

Comment: it always be either 0 and 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($company->leaders->where('number', '1')->count() === $company->leaders->count())
{
    return 1;
} else if ($company->leaders->where('number', '0')->count() > 0)
{
    return 0;
}
```